# CakePHP: Accessing the form helper's "current" model as supplied to $form->create()

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3

In my CakePHP 1.3 application, I need a form control that is:

1. Comprised of multiple form elements, and
2. Reusable in more than one form. I'd like to avoid code duplication if I can.

So, I'm creating an element that outputs my form control, and have hit a roadblock when it comes to populating the control with values on an edit action. Now, when you're using the default field types, CakePHP does this for you, but I need to get information out of `$this->data` and do it myself in this case.

The problem is that `$this->data` looks like this:

```
array(
    'Model' => array( /* fields from Model */ ),
    'AnotherModel' => array( /* fields from AnotherModel */ )
);
```

Within my reusable element, I don't know what model my field belongs to. However, I told this information to the Form Helper when I called `$form->create()` (in the view that includes the element I'm writing), so it seems like it should be able to tell me. And indeed, the [API documentation for the FormHelper class](http://api13.cakephp.org/class/form-helper) tells of a `defaultModel` property, but sadly, this property is empty.

Now, the simple solution is to pass the model in as a parameter. I can do that. But, I'd like to avoid parameter bloat where I can, and it seems like this ought to be possible, but I can't figure out how. Is there a way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I feel a bit sheepish. I should have checked the superclasses before posting. FormHelper inherits from AppHelper, which inherits from Helper, and Helper has a `model()` method that does the trick.

Lesson learned. :)

Answer (score 0):

Sidestepping the question, but an alternative would be to subclass the FormHelper and add a custom method to create the control:

```
App::import('Helper', 'Form');

class CustomFormHelper extends FormHelper {
    public function customControl() {
        $control = $this->input(…);
        $control.= $this->checkbox(…);
        return $control;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer prompted me to dig into the code to figure out how FormHelper figures out what model to use, which, in hindsight, I probably should have done first. So, thanks. :)